# fix position of arrows icons?

Tags: html, css

May be this question asked hundred times before but i can't able to figure it out what i am doing wrong

```
<div id="myNav" class="overlay" style="height: 100%; width: 100%;">

<div class="pdf-navigation">

<a class="navigator previousbtn" href="1">

<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-left" style="float:left;font-size:30px;color:#eee;margin-top:25%;z-index:3">

</span> </a>

<a class="navigator nextbtn" href="3">

<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-circle-arrow-right" style="float:right;font-size:30px;color:#eee;opacity:1;margin-top:25%;z-index:3">

</span></a>

/// pdf will loaded here in overlay screen 

</div>
```

css

```
.glyphicon-circle-arrow-left {

    float: left;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #eee;
    margin-top: 25%;
    z-index: 3;
}

.glyphicon-circle-arrow-right {

    float: right;
    font-size: 30px;
    color: #eee;
    opacity: 1;
    margin-top: 25%;
    z-index: 3;


}
```

what happening is when i scroll pdf these navigations icons are also 
scrolling i want them to be fixed.How can i achieve that?

i tried position relative to parent div and absolute to child spans...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use position: fixed

> fixed: The element is positioned relative to the browser window

More can be found [here](https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_position.asp)

best practice is to wrap all controls/icons in a div set its position to fixed.

---

Here's a [JSFiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/Lwc94weu/)

div with `pdf-navigation` class is over all with fixed position, put your controls inside it.

```
.pdf-navigation {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  position: fixed;
  top: 0px;
  left: 0px;
  z-index: 999999;
}
```

load your PDF or whatever content you want inside the div with id `content`

Comment: i tried that too but right arrows overlaps with left arrow

Comment: can you provide a jsfiddle? I don't have access to glyphicons

Comment: couldn't create working fiddle as pdf are need to  be loaded

Comment: I'll try to reproduce and get back to you.

Comment: thanks  > wrap all controls/icons in a div and div and set its position to fixed this helped me thanks

Comment: but now only problem left is href on icons are not working now

Comment: it works in the JSFiddle, make sure zindex in hight enough so the controls are above everything else.